# How to use injected dependency in a angular service?

Tags: angularjs

I am creating a custom service which logs a user in to my system. In this service, I need to use core services such as `$http` - How do I actually depend these to be used in my service?

My current code:

```
.factory('loginService', ['$http', '$rootScope', function() {

        var login = function(){
            console.log($http);
        }

        return {login : login};

}])
```

I call the login function from a controller like so

```
loginService.login();
```

I hoped that my console will output the `$http` object I injected, but it's returning undefined.

How do I access this in the correct way?

Comment: to me it looks like you want to do write a service instead of a factory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the dependencies to your function arguments:

```
.factory('loginService', ['$http', '$rootScope', function($http, $rootScope) {
    //You can use $http and $rootScope here now
}
```

See [the official docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di) for more info on Dependency Injection in angular

Answer (score 0):

Services you inject need to be passed as arguments of the function:

```
['$http', '$rootScope', function($http, $rootScope)
```

By the way, you'll need to do the same where you're trying to use it:

```
app.controller(['loginService', function (loginService) {
  loginService.login();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var myapp = angular.module('mainApp', []);

myapp.controller('myController', ['$scope', 'myFactory', function($scope, myFactory) {
    myFactory.login();
}]);

myapp.factory('myFactory', ['$http', function($http) {
    var services = {};

    services.login = function() {
      console.log($http);
    }

    return services;
}]);
```

View:

```
<div ng-app='mainApp' ng-controller='myController'></div>
```